# Excel VBA - unexpected output format with TextToColumns

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to copy the data of the one column which contains all number and pasting this column into another sheet but it shows somewhere as exponatial value and somewhere two decimal point digit (i.e.0.800857.511)
even though I'm using following code to convert the column as text.

**my actual values is :"4582608044" after pasting it into anther Sheet it shows "0.800857.511"**

```
 xlshtVFAST_SQL.Columns(12).TextToColumns D, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Please help me out,thanks in advance

Comment: Your code needs to set the columns to format as text after you paste.

Comment: @Dai even i apply formating code after pasting it shows same result

Comment: (a) What is the address pointed to by the variable `D`?  (Is it an appropriate size to receive the output?)  (b) What is the formatting of the cells in `D` **prior** to the copy?